# MS turning off Basic Authentication for Exchange Online in 2020

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, pop3, office365, oauth

MS will be depricating basic auth on pop3 october 2020.

Does pop3 will continue to work after that?

Is it possible to use OAuth with a pop3 connection ?
I can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using POP3 with Exchange Server?

Comment: It's a command line program that is creating Tiket based on incoming mail.

Answer (score 2):

This is all described in [this technet article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4521831/exchange-online-deprecating-basic-auth).

> Basic Authentication is superseded by Modern Authentication (based on
>   OAuth 2.0). Customers are encouraged to move to apps that support
>   Modern Authentication prior to the Basic Authentication removal in
>   October 2020. After October 2020 apps will not be able to use Basic
>   Authentication when connecting to Exchange Online
>
> This change only affects commercial M365 at this time, not our
>   consumer service Outlook.com users. It impacts Exchange ActiveSync
>   (EAS), IMAP, POP, and Remote PowerShell.

Comment: This article describe that MS is deprecating basic auth. My question is how to use OAuth with pop3 and the article doesn't talk about that...

Comment: This is not your question as it is written. Your question was: "Is it possible to use OAuth with a pop3 connection", answer: yes, with Modern Authentication based on OAuth 2.0.

Comment: I can't find any doc on how do you connect to pop3 using modern authentication. I know that I need to obtain the OAuth token but how do I connect to pop3 with this token... That's why it is not clear to me if pop3 is supported with modern authentication even though the above article say it is.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) and [that](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/)

Comment: This is probably the answer to my question : > To make it easier to migrate your existing applications to use OAuth 2.0, we are making significant investments to our service that include OAuth 2.0 support for POP, IMAP, and background application support for Remote PowerShell MFA module. We will be sharing more information on these new features over the coming months.

Comment: joeqwerty's question still stands: why use POP3 at all? I'm sure you could implement something..."nicer"